# Visual Studio Team System 2008 Localhost Controller Access Denied Restarting Rig for Load Test

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2008, automated-tests

I have two basic issues:

1. I can't seem to get the "Restart Rig" to work when the Controller is listed as 'localhost'.
2. I can't seem to get the agent to run as expected in the load test.

Here are the details:

I am using Visual Studio Team System 2008 with a Load Test. On the Windows XP system running Visual Studio, I have installed the Visual Studio Team Test Controller. On another Windows 2003 Standard system, I have installed the Visual Studio Team Test Agent (I will call these the Controller and Agent, respectively).

I believe I have set up the Agent correctly using the command:

> AgentConfigUtil.exe /controller:

The log file for this action indicates the agent was successfully added to the controller for both machines using the login account I was logged in with.

On the Controller, within Visual Studiio, I can select `Test | Administer Test Controllers` from the menu. In the Controller drop-down, I select "localhost". I have my "Load Test Result Store" correctly configured, and I add the Agent as defined. The Agent status is "Ready".

I then click on the "Restart Rig" button and receive the following message:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
Rig failed to restart for controller 'localhost'.
The following error was reported
Access is denied.
```

I am logged into both systems with a domain account that has local admin access to both machines.

Both the Controller and Agent services (running on their respective machines), have the "Log On As" user as my domain user with appropriate password. Both services are running without problems.

On the controller, I have the following groups: TeamTestAgentService, TeamTestControllerAdmins, and TeamTestControllerUsers. My domain account is a member of each group as well.

Note that if I select the name of the machine rather than 'localhost' in the Controller drop-down for the "Administer Test Controller" dialog, then the "Restart Rig" seems to work without any problems. Honestly, I'm not sure which is appropriate or correc for this situation. I would think these settings (localhost vs. machine name) were equivalent.

Finally, using the `Test | Edit Test Run Configuration`, I have created the following:

1. Test Run Configuration where the "Select location to run tests"is set to "Local" and the name of the Agent is in the name/value pair box.
2. Test Run Configuration where the "Select location to run tests" is set to "Remote" and the Agent is in the name/value pair box.

If I select the active configuration as the first one listed above, the test runs but I get no indication that the Agent is being used for the test. Yes, I do get an additional dialog telling me that: "You specified to execute test run remotely on a local machine. Are you sure you want to do that instead of executing locally?"

If I select the active configuration as the second one above, I get a "Test Run Error" of: "Failed to queue test run 'username@machinename time': Test run 'username@machinename time' cannot be executed on controller MACHINENAME. No agent matches the specified agent properties.

I've searched MSDN, I've read the appropriate articles on how to perform these actions ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182636%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182637%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)), but these articles are very basic and don't really help me much.

I'd appreciate any insight for getting my test configuration working correctly. Basically, I want to be able to run load tests with the agent working.